# HTTP API deprected warnings UTF_8, Scheme, ThreadSafeClientConnManager

Tags: java, http

I'm new java. I created a java project to call my webservice(Servlet,Tomcat6.0).
To use http i had added the following jar files
1. httpclient-4.2.1
2. httpcore-4.2.1

For methods(In Bold) below i'm getting type deprecated warnings and not able to run the project.

```
HTTP.**UTF_8**
aSchemeRegistryL.register(new **Scheme**("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
ClientConnectionManager ccm = new **ThreadSafeClientConnManager**(aHttpParamsL, aSchemeRegistryL);
```

Help me to rectify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time - check your java docs - they'll suggest an alternative class.  See:
[ThreadSafeClientManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html)

And it will suggest instead of ThreadSafeClientManager use: PoolingClientConnectionManager

[PoolingClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html)

As for the Scheme class, if you look at the javadocs, the class itself isn't deprecated, but the constructor you are using is:
[Scheme](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme.html)

Answer (score 17):

For `HTTP.UTF_8` the alternative is `Consts.UTF_8`. It's weird they don't mention that in the docs...

Comment: Consts.UTF_8 is a Charset whereas HTTP.UTF_8 is a String. HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(HttpParams httpParams, String charset) is expecting a String, not the Consts Charset. Thank you for letting us know about Consts, but it isn't a suitable replacement at this time.

Comment: Seems like you could use Consts.UTF_8.name(), .displayName(), or .toString(); as they all return the name property as a String.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadSafeClientConnManager class is deprecated, use `PoolingClientConnectionManager` and the constructor for `Scheme` you are using is deprecated too, use the other constructor found in that class.

As for the deprecated warnings, check that in Eclipse (I'm assuming you're using Eclipse, otherwise check for similar options in your IDE) that under Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings you don't have "Deprecated API" set to "Error" status.