# org.apache.http is deprecated, what to use?

Tags: java

I have an app that in order to download `Json` data uses `org.apache.http`
this is the class I use in order to make the request:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ServiceHandler {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity,HTTP.UTF_8);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

The problem is that every import from `org.apache.http` is deprecated and I don't know if i'll have problem using this class. Can someone point me to the right direction in order to "update" my class using non-deprecated methods?

**EDIT:**
From the Android M documentation:

This preview removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more efficient because it reduces network use through transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

So my app will crash using that class right?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of DefaultHttpClient use

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

And Instead of HTTP.UTF_8 use

```
StandardCharsets.UTF_8
```

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP.UTF_8 the alternative is Consts.UTF_8. It's weird they don't mention that in the docs. Consts.UTF_8 is a Charset whereas HTTP.UTF_8 is a String. HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(HttpParams httpParams, String charset) is expecting a String, not the Consts Charset.

For string we can use by String.valueOf(Consts.UTF_8)

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17133608/5059725)